# Center Align NavItem in React Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've been at this for ages and can't seem to work out how to do it. At the moments the `NavItem`'s in my NavBar are aligned to the left. I want them centered. I have tried reading the documentation here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/ but it doesn't work.

Here is my Navbar:

```
<div className="container">
  <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
      <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav  variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey="/home">
          <NavItem>
              <NavLink to="/newSite/details">Details</NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
              <NavLink to="/newSite/tours">Tours</NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
              <NavLink to="/newSite/pois">POIs</NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
</div>
```

Comment: as per the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#alignment-and-orientation) adding this `className="justify-content-center" ` it should work or your css is getting overwritten

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes I tried that and no success, I added it to the `<Nav>` and I have to external css

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add className="justify-content-center" in your Nav opening tag. If you're trying to center your Nav Items within a Navbar and Navbar.Collapse, add an inline style with flex: 1.

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg">
<Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
<Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
   <Nav className="justify-content-center" style={{ flex: 1}}>
     <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
     </Nav.Item>
     <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/home">Collection</Nav.Link>
     </Nav.Item>
     <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/home">Contact</Nav.Link>
     </Nav.Item>
     <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/home">Blog</Nav.Link>
     </Nav.Item>
   </Nav>
</Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Check out the "Alignment and orientation" section in the React Bootstrap Documentation. - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/